# Why is the "view" command link working only the first time I click it? How do I make it work for all links?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm using [a Developer Force example](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_Compound_Views_Using_Visualforce) to recreate that Visualforce page.  It works except for the fact that clicking on the "view" link only works once.  How do I make it work for each and every link / case?

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="MyConsoleController">
    <apex:form >

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Cases Cockpit"/>

    <div id="caseInfo" style="float:left;width:25%">
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Cases">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myCases}" var="case">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink value="View" action="{!viewCase}">
                        <apex:param name="caseId" value="{!case.Id}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!case.Subject}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!case.Status}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;width:73%">
        <apex:detail id="caseDetail" subject="{!selectedCase.Id}" relatedList="false" title="false"/>
    </div>

    <div style="width:100%">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Solutions">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!solutions}" var="sol">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink value="View" action="{!viewSolution}">
                        <apex:param name="caseId" value="{!sol.Id}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Solution #" value="{!sol.SolutionNumber}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!sol.SolutionName}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!sol.Status}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class MyConsoleController {

    public Case selectedCase { get; set; }

    public Solution[] getSolutions() {
        return [SELECT Id, SolutionNumber, SolutionName, Status FROM Solution];
    }

    public Case[] getMyCases() {
        return [SELECT Id, Subject, Status FROM Case WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
            AND Status != 'Closed'];
    }

    public PageReference viewCase() {
        String caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseId');
        selectedCase = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId];
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference viewSolution() {
        String solId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('solId');
        return new PageReference('/' + solId);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you click it a second time? Also, can you cut down the vf and controller a bit to just what you need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just copied the code directly from the wiki article and it worked without any issue. Can you try this under an admin user?

Comment: @grigriforce really? hmm, i did the same and it didn't work. I'll try again maybe. Well when i click on one case when the page just loaded, it shows the detail view, but after that none of the other links works, when I click on them it just does nothing at all.

Comment: Can you add the debug log from when you click the view link the second time?

Comment: @grigriforce I checked the debug log and there's nothing there, so it's not erroring out.

Comment: in theory it looks like something that's working on first load, and then not working after that.

Comment: Wondering if adding a reRender of the case detail on click of the link would change anything. reRender = "caseDetail"

Comment: If there is nothing in the debug log then you are not even running the pagereference method when you click the button. Try removing the "action={!viewcase}" parameter and setting immediate="true" on the commandlink and see what happens. It should refresh the page.

Comment: @grigriforce yes it refreshes the page when i did that

Comment: If you put the action method back in and leave immediate="true" on what happens?

Comment: same issue, first time it works, then after that does not. this is so weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that I see is on lines 27 - 31 (copied below) and causes it so that you cannot view solutions.  I was able to reproduce that error; however there's no error for the case links.  I can click those without any problems just like @grigriforce.

```
  <apex:column >
    <apex:commandLink value="View" action="{!viewSolution}"> 
        <apex:param name="caseId" value="{!sol.Id}"/>
    </apex:commandLink>
  </apex:column>
```

Note that it is assigning solution Id to a parameter of caseId.  Then in the controller `viewSolution` method it has:

```
 String solId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('solId');
```

So, `solId` is null and it gives you the not found / no longer exists URL.  Change the Visualforce to:

```
<apex:param name="solId" value="{!sol.Id}"/>
```

After you make that change the controller method will have a value of the clicked Solution's ID for `solId` instead of null and the `PageReference` that is constructed will go to the Solution's detail page.

**Update** There is another error if the detail page (from the page layout) has the Submit for Approval button on it because it has an html name attribute of `submit` which conflicts with the form's submit function.

A solution for that is to break the page up in to two forms, leaving the detail page out of the forms.

The Visualforce page would be changed to:

```
<apex:page controller="MyConsoleController">

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Cases Cockpit"/>

<!-- One form begins here -->
<apex:form >
    <div id="caseInfo" style="float:left;width:25%">
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Cases">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myCases}" var="case">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink value="View" action="{!viewCase}">
                        <apex:param name="caseId" value="{!case.Id}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!case.Subject}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!case.Status}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>
</apex:form>
<!-- One form ends here, leaving the detail page out -->
    <div style="float:right;width:73%">
        <apex:detail id="caseDetail" subject="{!selectedCase.Id}" relatedList="false" title="false"/>
    </div>
<!-- Second form begins here, leaving the detail page out -->
<apex:form >
    <div style="width:100%">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Solutions">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!solutions}" var="sol">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink value="View" action="{!viewSolution}">
                        <apex:param name="caseId" value="{!sol.Id}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Solution #" value="{!sol.SolutionNumber}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!sol.SolutionName}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!sol.Status}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>
</apex:form>
<!-- Second form ends here -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: i ran google dev tool console and this is the error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function testcase:36
jsfcljs testcase:36
onclick

Comment: I cannot reproduce your HTMLFormElement error with the copy and pasted code; however, that error means that there is something else on the page that is a property of the form that is named submit.  For example, if I add `<input type="text" name="submit" />` to the page within the form I get that error.  SF is using JavaScript behind the scenes to submit the form and I suspect at some point there's a form.submit() call.  When you name something 'submit' it tries to call that, but it's not a function; hence the error.

Comment: I found out that when I remove the "Submit for approval" button from the page layout it works. That button was made by someone else as part of a workflow I think. Thoughts?

Comment: @user988 - That does it for me too.  I didn't have the Submit for approval button.  I added it and then I inspected the HTML source and saw the Submit for Approval button's name attribute is submit.  I have updated my answer with a solution for that.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Wow, thanks for the help. I really appreciate it, was cracking my head with this one! Just could not figure it out. Cheers!